# Previous Navigation View Controller Stays After Pushing ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: This is my initial view]

This is my initial view

So I'm  going to navigate using bottom right button.And landing here :

[image]

After I pressed OK. I want to go back 2 previous screen which is "Schedule" page.

[image]

And here is my result. I've landed page I wanted but top left says "< Templates" and I don't want that. I want to go back and start everything fresh.

Here is my code snippet triggers when pressing okay :

```
UIViewController* vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"autoModeViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Here is my storyboard looks like :

[image]

Comment: Why are you pushing a new view controller if you want to go back to the previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navigation heirarchy is wrong. 
You need to do something like this :

Navigation Controller -> ScheduleViewController -> TemplateViewController
from ScheduleViewController you need to push TemplateViewController on button tap and when back button of TemplateViewController is tapped you need to pop the ViewController so that only ScheduleViewController remains on top of the stack.

Tell me if you need more details.

Comment: But my ScheduleViewController already have a NavigationViewcontroller in it.

Comment: then why do you need to put a navigation controller between ScheduleViewController and TemplateViewController?

Comment: When I'm not putting everything goes wrong. I don't understand why either. How can i do without putting navigation controller ?

Comment: Give me a minute I m sending a sample app.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Let me take a look at it.

Comment: I didn't open your storyboards. I just don't have luck today , I guess..

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing to the navigation controller when you actually want to pop from it.

Try replacing your code with just this:

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Edit:

Further explanation:
When you first start out the navigation controller looks like this:

`NavController -> Schedule`

Then you push the template view controller to it so it looks like this:

`NavController -> Schedule -> Template`

The way you have it, you're pushing an instance of the first view controller onto the navigation controller, so the navigation controller now looks like this when you hit the OK button:

`NavController -> Schedule -> Template -> Schedule`

If you pop it, the navigation controller will look like this again:

`NavController -> Schedule`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried that too. I've tried your solution and also I've tried `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. But they didn't work. I couldn't even go back. By the way my view hiearchy was always this way and 2 days ago it was working the way what I want. But somehow, it didn't now. I think it's about segues or push. However I haven't figure it out yet.